# Spring integration: receive duplicated messages from pollable channel

Tags: spring-integration

I declared a pollable channel channel.request, after a transformation of the paylod of the channel to an object, I note that some messages arrived duplicated to service activator.

My code is the following:

```
<int:channel id="channel.request">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="updateImsi.channel"
    output-channel="updateImsi.channel.withHeader">
    <int:header name="content-type" value="application/json" />
    <int:header name="msisdn" expression="payload.split('${separator}')[0]" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:transformer input-channel="updateImsi.channel.withHeader"
    output-channel="channel.request" ref="imsiMsgTransformer"
    method="transform">
</int:transformer>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel.request"
ref="updateImsiHttpResponseMessageHandler" method="handleMessage">
<int:poller fixed-delay="1000"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>
```

the trace from service activator and transformer:

transformer: m2

serviceactivator payload: m2

transformer: m3

transformer: m4

transformer: m5

serviceactivator payload: m4

serviceactivator payload: m4

serviceactivator payload: m4

Answer (score 0):

Whenever debugging issues like this, the simplest thing to to is turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` and follow the message flow. Be sure to include the thread name in the log. If you still can't figure out what's going on post the log.

My "best" guess from your "trace" is that either the service activator or the transformer is not thread-safe.